# How to subract the nested array object values in mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to know how to subtract the nested array object field values in mongodb.

```
{
  Active: [
    {min: 1, energy: 24},
    {min: 2, energy: 34},
    {min: 3, energy: 65}
  ]
}
```

Expected output:
Difference: 65-24 = 41

I have tried this:

```
{
  $project: {
    Difference: {
      $subtract: ["$active.3.energy","$active.0.energy"]
    }
  }
}
```

query2:

```
{
  $project: {
    Difference: {
      $subtract: ["$active.$[n].energy","$active.0.energy"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it always just 3 entries in the `Active` array?   Is the real goal to find the difference between the greatest and the least value of `energy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "Difference": {
        "$subtract": [
          {"$arrayElemAt": ["$Active.energy", 2]},
          {"$arrayElemAt": ["$Active.energy", 0]}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XGcV17rdRTL).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the `Active` array can be of arbitrary length and we wish to get the difference between the greatest and least value of `energy`.  Here's a solution:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    // Ensure sorted ordering of array:                                          
    {$addFields: {
        'Active': {$sortArray: {'input':'$Active', 'sortBy': { energy: 1 }}}
    }}              

    // $arrayElemAt is 0-based, so need $size:'$Active' - 1:                     
    ,{$project: {
        'difference': {$subtract: [
            {$arrayElemAt:['$Active.energy', {$subtract:[{$size:'$Active'},1]} ]},
            {$arrayElemAt:['$Active.energy',0]} ] }
    }}
]);
```